# Property 'snapshotChanges' does not exist on type 'void'. ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

how can I fix this error ??
I saw the video tutorial and I followed it correctly, but why did I encounter this error?

```
onContextChange(ctxt: string): void {
this.songsList$ = this.songsService.assembleBandFilteredList(ctxt).snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
  return changes.map(c=> ({
    key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
  }));
});
```

}

Comment: What's the `this.songsService` object like? It seems that `assembleBandFilteredList` method is either incorrectly defined or incorrectly used, be we can't figure out what it is without context.

Answer (score 1):

Check the songs.service.ts file under services to include any string.

`assembleBandFilteredList(ctxt: string): any {
 return(this.filterByString(ctxt));
}`